# Sending String through Segue in IOS Mobile APP

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

Hello I am trying to create a simple Rock Paper Scissors app to learn IOS Development in Swift. However, I am having trouble sending information through the my first view controller called InitialChoice to my second view controller Results. I have confirmed that the @IBAction function `play again` is working fine because "Hello" will print out once I press the play again button. I will also add a picture for my story board to get an idea.

[My Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUmIE.png)

This is the code for the first Segue:

```
var decision: String = ""

func choiceSelected(){
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {
        let secondVC: Results = segue.destination as! Results

        secondVC.decision1 = decision


    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "madeChoice", sender: self)

}

@IBAction func selectedPaper(_ sender: Any) {
    decision = "paper"
    choiceSelected()
}
@IBAction func selectedRock(_ sender: Any) {
    decision = "rock"
    choiceSelected()

}
@IBAction func selectedScissors(_ sender: Any) {
    decision = "scissors"
    choiceSelected()

}
```

This is the code for the Second Segue

```
var decision1: String = ""


@IBAction private func playAgain() {
    if (decision1 == "paper") {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print(decision1)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
```

}

Comment: `prepare for segue` func should be `override`n inside `UIViewContoller`, just get it outside of your function and this should work

Comment: @JuicyFruit Thank you so much! That worked perfectly. No it is sending over the string.